# UIImagePickerController does not load image

Tags: ios, image, uiimagepickercontroller

This seems like a relatively simple issue but it has me stumped. Any help / insight is appreciated.

Problem:

I have a UIImagePickerController button on my screen and would like to initially load with a custom image until the user selects an image from the camera roll (the custom image is just a + sign). However the UIImagePickerController button appears blank until the user clicks it for the first time. After the first click, it works fine but for some reason it does not initialize with the default image. I have pasted my code from viewDidLoad method in the controller.

Code :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.detailItem cardName]];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
imgPickerButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
```

So what am I doing wrong? Any insight is appreciated and thanks in advance for your help.

[image: This illustrates the design view of the screen in storyboard]

[image: Screenshot of how the view appears until the user clicks the button]

Answer (score 0):

Debug it?

```
//Your Code

//Debug it with muscle
NSLog(@"\n**** I Love Debug Statements! *****\ndocumentsPath: %@\n filePath: %@\ndetailItem: %@\ndefault image: %@", documentsPath, filePath, self.detailItem, imgPickerButton.imageView.image);
```

My guess is that your "self.detailItem" is nil when you try to call this the first time...

Comment: Nope - checked that already. It is working fine. It has the right file name and as mentioned, the image loads after the user clicks it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

from the picture it looks like this is a part of a tableview? If this is the case then the tableview cell is getting loaded before your above code is

Comment: It is just a UIButton - please see original note. I have uploaded another image to show this

Comment: ah well then i think i see the problem.

Comment: you need to do [imgPickerButton setImage: forState:] to set the image initially

Comment: I added the following statement to the end :     [imgPickerButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:pngData] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; and it didnt work. Now the image doesnt load even after first click!!

Comment: Hmm interesting, that should work. Are you sure there is an actually an image in that "pngData"? And what code are you using after the first click? What method are you using to update the image after a click?

Comment: Figured out the problem - see below for solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out!! I was setting the image for the UIButton in the viewDidLoad method. Which is a method called after the view is drawn. Hence the default image was not appearing until the first click, at which time the UIButton is redrawn. To solve this issue I moved the code to **awakeFromNib** method and voila!! it works fine. The default image loads smoothly...